# Как подключиться к sql server'у не через localhost?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Есть строка подключения:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=remembersdb;Integrated Security=True";
```

И есть метод для проверки:

```
    private void GetPeople() {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try {
            connection.Open();
            richTextBox1.Text+=("Подключение открыто");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) {
            richTextBox1.Text += (ex.Message);
        }
        finally {
            connection.Close();
            richTextBox1.Text += ("Подключение закрыто...");
        }
    }
```

Все работает без ошибок,только если Data Source=localhost. Однако, если обратиться к инстансу SQL server'a, имя которого указано в Configuration Manager (.\MSSQLSERVER), то ошибка. Протокол TCP включен:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -na | find "LISTE" | find "1433"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1433              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Пробовал .\SQLEXPRESS, .\MSSQLSERVER, local. Что же ставить на место localhost?

Comment: "...если обратиться к инстансу SQL server'a...", а где установлен этот самый инстанс? На той же машине где вы программируете?

Comment: Фаервол, реквизиты доступа в БД? Что `ex.Message` содержит в момент эксепшена?

Comment: зачем вообще что-то ставить на место локалхост? поставьте 127.0.0.1, какая разница? в конфиг менеджере точка обозначеат локалхост,  Зачем пробовать sqlexpress, если ваш инстанс mssqlserver ? для клиентского приложения это будет `localhost\mssqlserver`